# Coplanarity of tangent points

Tags: solid-geometry, spheres

If the segments AB, BC, CD and DA are tangent to a sphere, how to prove that the tangent points are coplanar?

Comment: This is one of the more interesting questions I found on this site. How did you came about this one?

Comment: It is correct! Are you still looking for the proof?

Comment: Yes, I don't know if any of the two approaches I'm considering now would give a proof, so I'd still like to know the answer.

And the problem is from Данияр Муштари's book.

Comment: What are your approaches?  You will benefit from solving it so I would prefer you do the work:)